# Why did Apache IoTDB popped "Request method `POST` not supported" warning?

Tags: database, time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

When I try to set Apache IoTDB standalone version, IoTDB cannot start and a warning said `WARN o. s.w. s.m. support. DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolved org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedexception: Request method` POST `not supported`. Seems like the startup configuration has something wrong, so I want to know what configuration do I still need to change?

Before I post this question, I checked all the questions tagged apache-iotdb, and I did not find the meaning explanation to this specific warning. The official guide also did not include this warning. Although the error message specifies `Request method POST`, which seems to be easy to identify what the problem is, I did not know what configuration this method is related to. Therefore, I choose to ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

What is your JDK version? To startup Apache IoTDB, the environment requires JDK1.8.0_162 and above. Check if your JDK version is lower than this requirement to cause the "Request method `POST` not supported" error.